# Is there a way to import GitHub issues to JIRA?

Tags: github, jira

My team use Jira and we often work with open source software which are hosted on GitHub.

I often get request from my PM to update the status which can sometimes easily be followed using the GitHub public issue openend on one of those open source project.

Is there a way I can link a GitHub issue to a Jira ticket and sync all the GitHub comment in this Jira ticket ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes, it is.

If you want some manual import, you can check [this Atlassian Community post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/What-s-the-best-way-to-migrate-Github-issues-into-Jira/qaq-p/751279).

As explained in here, you can perform with applying following steps:

1. Get list of issues in JSON format using following link from the browser

   [https://api.github.com/repos/\](https://api.github.com/repos/%5C)<repo-owner-name>/<repo-name>/issues?state:open
2. Convert JSON to CSV using any online converter
3. User Jira's External system import > choose CSV and upload the file.

Or, if you are looking for some programmatic way, you can check [following page](https://zmcddn.github.io/how-to-migrate-github-issues-to-jira.html) on zmccdn.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I can see here is that it is not sync (not automatic). So it does not solve our problem, it will just add manual action and risk of being unsync.

Comment: Well, if you want a real "sync", you may need some plugin to do that. As far as I know, current GitHub plugins are not covering GitHub issues for integration. Yes, it is not sync but you may write a script and schedule it

Comment: Or, a better approach is creating a listener and calling your custom integration code when new issue come in GitHub. This approach can automatize the process.